# a name for a class of cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, cardinals, forcing

I'm not a native English speaker; what S in SCar below might stand for ?

[image]

Comment: I think this might just be because $S$ comes after $R$ - $SCar$ is a technical modification of $RCar$ which is only introduced because it happens to come in handy later on. But I'm not certain.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You're probably right, but I can't help observing that, given that RCar stands for "regular cardinals", reasonable people might expect SCar to stand for "singular cardinals" or for "successor cardinals". Maybe the definition was chosen to discourage such reasonableness.